# How to get two error handling working on the same textbox simultaneously

Tags: c#

I got some work that needs a certain number that only works on 7-digit or 11-digit and I need to catch the error when its not those.

Thing is, it would give a me a error all because I technically did a error by one of them.

I made my code like this

```
if (No < 1000000 || No > 1000000 || No < 10000000000 || No > 10000000000)
{
  var err = new Exception("a Contact Number must be 7-digit or 11-digit only");
  err.Source = "Contacts Requirements";
  throw err;
}
```

I could show more if I want to.

Comment: So you want to display an error if the number is neither 7 not 11 digits, or equivalently, if is not 7 digits AND not 11 digits.

Comment: Btw: the IDE in use to edit the code has absolutely _nothing_ to do with this error. FWIW you could be writing in Notepad.exe

Comment: Also: "textbox" leads me to assume this could be WinForms or WPF. Both of which have their respective  idiomatic input validation. None of which use exceptions and especially not directly the general `Exception` type.

Answer (score 2):

Since the condition must be that the length of the number is **(NOT 7) AND (NOT 11)**, you can write (assuming that `No` is of type `long` or `ulong`):

```cs
if ( (No < 1000000 || No > 9999999) && (No < 10000000000 || No > 99999999999) ) {
    ...
}
```

Or, with pattern matching:

```cs
if ( No is (< 1000000 or > 9999999) and (< 10000000000 or > 99999999999) ) {
    ...
}
```

But you could also test the length of TextBox text instead:

```cs
if (textBox1.Text.Length is not 7 and not 11) {
    ...
}
```